# Screen command disable the control key ctrl-a to use it in vim?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vim, gnu-screen

I sometimes open vim with screen linux command but since ctrl-a is considered as control key I cannot increment numbers using the same combination inside the editor.

I don't want to remap entirly ctrl-a but is there a way to disable it so I can use it in vim ?

Comment: You can press Ctrl-A twice to send it to Vim inside screen. Would that be fine?

Comment: @IngoKarkat it is obvious that you have never used  `screen` linux command but thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes, I use `tmux`, and there it works like that (only that Ctrl-B is the default prefix). [Just checking](http://transnum.blogspot.de/2008/11/send-ctrl-to-sessions-in-screen.html), for screen that should be Ctrl-A a.

Comment: @IngoKarkat Ctrl-A twice is not Ctrl-A a. thanks a lot you are magic.

Comment: So, does that already answer your question? Alternatively, you could also remap the increment operation in Vim.

Comment: Ah, that was easy. It's still a good question, for those that aren't able to find this in the man page on their own. I've added a full answer. Happy Vimming!

Answer (score 5):

In `screen`, you can pass on the prefix key via `Ctrl-A` followed by `a` (cp. [here](http://transnum.blogspot.de/2008/11/send-ctrl-to-sessions-in-screen.html)). In `tmux`, this would be `Ctrl-b` `Ctrl-b`. Either can be adapted in the tool's configuration file.

Alternatively, you could remap the increment inside Vim, e.g. by putting the following into your `~/.vimrc`:

```
noremap <C-q> <C-a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can remap screen to use a different escape if you want. I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>t</kbd>.

In `.screenrc`:

```
escape ^Tt
```

This will map the screen metacharacter to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>t</kbd>. And it also maps the literal sequence of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>t</kbd> + <kbd>t</kbd> to send a `Ctrl-t` through to the application running inside screen.

This would free <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> so screen will not be using it, and it will be passed through to Vim.